# how can i count status changed/updated by all categories for a specific month (all categories even not records are not associated/found )

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

i want to show all categories(even records are not found) and count projects status updates/changes for a given month by categories names (all categories lists)

I have a categories (list of category), investment (list of investors investments including category_id from categories), status table which has a name with pre implementation, implementation and operations states. a project contains project id, name, start date fields. both status and projects have a many to many relationship called project_status table contains project_id, status_id, date_of_progress.

I want to count all projects within this month who has update/change their status_id by categories names

from pre-implementation to implementations from implementations to operations from pre-implementation to operations

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `categories` (`cat_id`, `name`, `description`) VALUES
(1, 'agriculture', ''),
(2, 'manufactures ', ''),
(3, 'Technology', ''),
(4, 'services', ''),
(5, 'industries', ''),
(6, 'other', '');



CREATE TABLE `investments` (
  `investment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `investment_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `investments` (`investment_id`, `investment_name`, `cat_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Company A', 3),
(2, 'Company B', 4),
(3, 'Company C', 1),
(4, 'Company D', 2),
(5, 'Company E', 3),
(6, 'Company F', 4),
(7, 'Company G', 1),
(8, 'Company H', 2);

CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_name_tg` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `status` (`status_id`, `status_name`, `description`, `status_name_tg`) VALUES
(1, 'Pre Implementation', 'Operational', 'Pre Implementation'),
(2, 'Implementation', NULL, 'Implementation'),
(3, 'Operational', NULL, 'Operational'),
(4, 'Inactive', NULL, 'Inactive'),
(5, 'Cancellation', NULL, 'Cancellation');

CREATE TABLE `project_status` (
  `project_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reason_for_cancellation` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `project_status` (`project_status_id`, `status_id`, `time`, `project_id`, `reason_for_cancellation`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2019-02-24 21:51:50', 1, NULL),
(2, 2, '2019-03-26 21:52:57', 1, NULL),
(3, 1, '2019-04-30 21:57:57', 2, NULL),
(4, 1, '2019-05-26 22:04:08', 3, NULL),
(5, 3, '2019-08-24 22:06:36', 1, NULL),
(6, 2, '2019-08-11 22:07:05', 3, NULL),
(8, 1, '2019-08-01 00:14:41', 6, NULL),
(9, 1, '2019-08-09 12:11:22', 7, NULL),
(10, 1, '2019-08-09 12:15:22', 8, NULL),
(11, 3, '2019-08-14 10:07:49', 7, NULL),
(12, 2, '2019-08-14 10:10:45', 8, NULL),
(13, 2, '2019-08-26 17:16:02', 6, NULL),
(14, 3, '2019-08-26 17:16:02', 6, NULL);


CREATE TABLE `projects` (
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `investment_id` int(11) NOT NULL    
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `projects` (`project_id`, `name`, `start_date`, `investment_id`) VALUES
(1, 'site A', '2019-02-01 00:00:00', 1),
(2, 'site B', '2019-03-12 00:00:00', 2),
(3, 'Site C', '2019-04-04 00:00:00', 3),
(4, 'Site D', '2019-05-03 00:00:00', 4),
(5, 'site E', '2019-06-01 00:00:00', 5),
(6, 'site F', '2019-08-02 00:00:00', 6),
(7, 'Site J', '2019-08-01 00:00:00', 7),
(8, 'Site H', '2019-08-05 00:00:00', 8);
```

Below is the result of Augus 2019

```
+--------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
 | category_name| pre_implemntation | imp_operation | pre_operation |
 +------+-------+------------+-------------++-------------++--------+
 | agriculture  |     1             |          -    |           1   |
 | manufactures |     1             |          -    |           -   |
 | Technology   |     -             |          1    |           -   |
 | services     |     -             |          1    |           -   |
 | industries   |     -             |          -    |           -   |
 | other        |     -             |          -    |           -   |
 +--------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
```